Clipping mask between line art object and image
Really novice adobe illustrator user here with a question about implementing a clipping mask on two images.
Specifically, I'm trying to create a new image by clipping this line art of a bat to the background image. I have seen similar questions online that suggest highlighting both layers and selecting object/clipping mask/make. However, this just clips the outer box of the bat line art to the background image. Ideally, the background image would be clipped exactly to the shape of the bat and overlap would be discarded.
Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated, thanks!


Hi. Welcome to GDSE. The background looks like it's a raster image (made of pixels).  You can't use a raster image to make a clipping mask, it has to be vector. You can clip a raster image using a vector image, but not vice versa.

One thing that could work here is if you redraw the black outlines of the background shapes as vector, combine these shapes, and use those to clip the bat vector.

@BillyKerr I think my explanation in the original post was confusing. I am trying to clip the raster image of the recombination map using the vector outline of the bat. In that case, what would you suggest?

I see, in that case what you need is a simple bat outline. You'll need to redraw it manually probably - as it has to be a single closed path (without any gaps).

You can not create a clipping mask from disjointed pieces - well, you can, but the black parts of the bat become the mask shape. Is that what you want? Just the raster image inside the outline of the bat? To do that, make a compound path of all the bat pieces.. then it can be used as a clipping mask. If you want the interior of the bat to contain the raster image, you need a single closed shape of the bat. The bat, if it's vector, has gaps, holes, spaces -- you need the mask shape (the bat) to be a single closed path or compound path.

@Scott and [at]BillyKerr I ended up making a solid shape trace of the bat image using the pen tool, and then used the clipping mask tool. This allowed me to overlap the actual bat vector with the clipped raster in the same shape. Thank you both for your insights and recommendations!
